# Failed to create provisioning profile iOS - for a free profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to create a project in Xcode, Version 8.0 beta 6 (8S201h) and I'm getting this error.

[image]

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure of what are you looking for, but if you want to run the project, you can set "Team" to "None" Option.

Comment: I dont want to have an error in Signing / Status

Comment: I'd like to sign my app to publish it on the apple store

Answer (score 5):

Seen your image, I had the same issue and I solved this by,

Change 'Bundle Identifier' in general tab,

If its declared in info.plist file than change it in that file.

Clear project and run.

Change Bundle Identifier to 'gbs.AppMovilGera1' or something else.

Comment: Appear this : Your maximum App ID limit has been reached. You may create up to 10 App IDs every 7 days

Comment: Apple limits the free app id to 10 for 7 days. So you can not make more than 10 App ID's in 7 days. You have to wait for 7 days and build again.

Comment: There is one way to do this, If you have run any application using this free team than use that bundle identifier for this app and run the app.

Comment: I never build any apps yet. So how could I have passed the weekly limit ?

Comment: where is info.plist by default